# Is it currently possible to perform mediational analysis of an lmer() model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, mediation

Lets say I have a model where 100 participants responded to 100 items. I want to see if Property A predicts reaction time. I then want to see if its effect on reaction time is mediated by Property B.

So far I've analyzed the data with linear mixed effects models, with random subject and item effects. Is it possible to perform mediational analyses with such a model?

Here is some sample code.

```
set.seed(123)

library(lme4)

Subject <- rep(1:100, each = 100)
Item <- rep(1:100, times = 100)
RT <- rnorm(n = 10000, mean = 600)
Pred_A <- rnorm(10000)
Pred_B <- rnorm(10000)

dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(Subject, Item, RT, Pred_A, Pred_B))

dat$Subject <- as.factor(dat$Subject)
dat$Item <- as.factor(dat$Item)

m <- lmer(RT ~ Pred_A + (1|Subject) + (1|Item), data = dat)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this may be possible, but you need to consider whether the random effects structure is the same across the two models you need to run to evaluate mediation.

You want to test the mediation model: `Pred_A --> Pred_B --> RT`. This requires the model you have now, with `Pred_B` included as a an additional predictor:

```
m1 <- lmer(RT ~ Pred_A + Pred_B + (1|Subject) + (1|Item), data = dat)
```

It also requires a model with `Pred_B` as the outcome. And herein lies the question/problem:

- Does it make sense to include the same random effects structure in
  the model for `Pred_B` as in the model for `RT`?

If the answer is yes, then you can estimate that model and use the `mediation` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/vignettes/mediation.pdf) in R to test for indirect (mediated) effects.

If not, you can still estimate the model but will need to adjust the random effects. It should be doable in `mediation` based on the linked vignette (see section 4.2), but could be a bit challenging.

Comment: Are you sure the mediation package can handle crossed random factors? It seems not to work in my case.